# Reduce size of application icons in Ubuntu 18.04 notification tray

Tags: 18.04, icons, indicator, customization, notification-area

Why is the top bar notification area icon size bigger than the system icon size?

I tried to install topiconplus extension, but it doesn't help at all.

[image: Example.. Skype, Teamviewe, Remmina and MailSpring]